# Is there any antibody-forming immune system without immunological memory?

Tags: immune-system

Is it possible for an immune system to exist that makes antibodies but does not possess any kind of immunological memory? If so, what examples are there?

Comment: have you tried googling this?

Comment: @aaaaaa yes, but I couldn't find the answer of my question.

Comment: Disagree with the close votes. This may not be a particularly sophisticated question but it's certainly within the scope of biology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no system that makes antibodies but that doesn't have memory.

The title of this question <strike>is</strike> was originally very different from the body. The title asks if there's "any **immune system** without immunological memory", while the body asks if there's "any **immune system that makes antibodies** but has not immunological memory". That suggests you may think that antibodies are an essential part of an immune system, or that immune systems comprise only antibodies. Neither is true. The vast majority of animals have immune systems that do not have antibodies and that do not have immunological memory; for example, arthropods, the various kinds of worms, etc.

Immunological memory is a relatively recent addition to the immune system, having arisen approximately 400 million years ago, in the lineage that originated with shark-like fish.  The species that evolved from sharks -- fish, amphibians, reptiles, birds, mammals -- all have immunological memory, and all have antibodies. Those species that didn't arise from that lineage do not have antibodies, and with two exceptions do not have immunological memory.

- [The origins of vertebrate adaptive immunity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2919748/)

The exceptions are lampreys and hagfish, which have a common ancestor with sharks but which ended up forming an immune system that is related to, but often quite different from, that of sharks (and us). Lampreys and hagfish have molecules that are not antibodies but that function in a similar way, including having a form of immunological memory, though it's quite different from ours. So if you're looking for an example of something that *kind of* has antibodies but that *kind of* doesn't have immunological memory, that's as close as you're going to get.

- [Lamprey Immunity Poised to Evolve](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2002/10/lamprey-immunity-poised-evolve)
- [Harnessing 450 Million Years of Evolution: Lamprey Antibodies for Modern Biomarker Technology](http://www.immpressmagazine.com/harnessing-450-million-years-of-evolution-lamprey-antibodies-for-modern-biomarker-technology/)

Note that virtually all species, including mammals, have branches of the immune system that don't have immunological memory. Those branches don't have antibodies, though.

- [Innate Immunity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26846/)
- [The innate and adaptive immune systems](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0072580/)

Comment: I’m not sure I agree with your characterisation of immunological memory as recent. I couldn’t find its evolutionary age with a cursory search but for all I know CRISPR (an immunological memory) could well be ancient. Similar for other cell-based immune mechanisms that rely on integration of foreign genetic material.

Comment: I don't really accept that CRISPR is "immunological memory" other than in semantics.

Comment: Huh. How is it not?

Comment: Any argument that it is relies on semantics and definitions. I don't find that an interesting game to play. Bacteria may have "immunity", but they don't have "immune systems". I'm not saying you can't call it "immunological memory" if you want, I'm just saying that I don't call it that and I don't find attempts to shoehorn it into the same category to be at all interesting.

Comment: I’m not playing semantics games. But we *do* seem to have different definitions. There are different kinds of immune systems, and I wasn’t aware that there was a consensus(?) that bacteria’s immunity wouldn’t count as an immune system. In fact, I know researchers (apart from me) that would call it an immune system (and it’s trivial to find publications supporting this). So what about RNAi then? Is that also not an immune system? Because, once again, I know that others call it an immune system. I don’t think your definition has special status.

Comment: *I’m not playing semantics games. But we do seem to have different definitions.* That's what semantics means. Really, I don't want to make a big deal of this. What I'm saying is that bacterial "immunity" is so utterly different from animal immunity that there's virtually no biological insights to be gained from grouping them together. The dictionary certainly lets you do that, but there's no biological utility to it. It's like asking if a virus is alive. It tells you about the word "alive" but nothing about viruses. It's not (biologically) interesting.

Comment: Well “games” suggests that I’m baiting you but I’m not — rather, I simply don’t understand you. Your last comment clarified that somewhat although now I could complain about eukaryotic chauvinism (but I shan’t!).

Comment: thank you for your very specific answer. actually I already knew the broad-brush concept of the innate,acquired immunity, I'm sorry for confusing you. it's very interesting that there are such unusual  type of immune system(Lampreys,Hagfish) that you mentioned.

Comment: actually I was just wondering and thinking what if there wasn't immunological memory, then how would the immune system evolve, would it just increase its diversity of antibodies or would it decrease its delay time to activate and prepare acquired immunity system, are they two trade-off relationship etc... so these are the reason why I asked the question. anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Konrad Rudolph Thank you for proofread My informal and silly english grammar!

Comment: There seems to be some evidence of immunological memory in insects. See [this article](http://journals.plos.org/plospathogens/article?id=10.1371/journal.ppat.0030026), for example.

Comment: I wrote about that article, and others, on my blog in 2007: [Invertebrate memory, or wishful thinking?](http://www.iayork.com/MysteryRays/2007/10/25/invertebrate-memory-or-wishful-thinking/); also [here](http://www.iayork.com/MysteryRays/2007/11/19/social-immunity-in-ants/), [here](http://www.iayork.com/MysteryRays/2007/11/20/social-immunity-followup/), and [here](http://www.iayork.com/MysteryRays/2010/08/19/and-so-on-ad-infinitum/). TL;DR, very unlikely to be real immunological memory.